# Mailer Error: Message body empty need to send mail without chnage in body

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail-imap

I am having a problem to send email, where my body is empty, but in this mail I have attachments. w

What should I do to send my email to any user without enter any message or text in by `body` section?

[image: Here is my database, and row where my message is empty]

```
    <?php
    
    include('db.php');
     use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
     use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
     require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
    
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    
    $query = "select * from access where uid='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    try {  
    
        $mail->setFrom('sender@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress('receiver@gmail.com');
        
            if($row['attachments']!=null) 
            {
                $array = explode(",",$row['attachments']);
                $count = count($array);
                if($count > 0 && $row['attachments'] != 'null'){
                    for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
                            $file_to_attach = './attachment/' . $array[$i];
                            $mail->addAttachment($file_to_attach, $array[$i]); 
                    }
                }
            }
       
    
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
        $mail->Subject = $row['subject'];
        $mail->Body    = $row['body'];
    
        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried to put whitespace in body, or to send HTML mail with `&nbsp;`

Comment: If you're saying you want to send an empty message with attachments, PHPMailer won't let you send by default, but it will if you set `$mail->AllowEmpty = true;`.